# replacing navigation script in Wordpress using wp_dequeue_script - only works on home page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to make the navigational menu on a website I built toggled open by default. I am using Wordpress twentyseventeen theme.  I dug around in the theme files and found that the initial toggle state for the menu is set in navigation.js, and that navigation.js is enqueued in the parent theme's functions.php:

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'top' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyseventeen-navigation', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/navigation.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}
```

So I dequeued that script in my child theme's functions.php, then enqueued my updated version that sets the default toggle to on:

```
function drick_theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_dequeue_script( 'twentyseventeen-navigation');
wp_enqueue_script( 'drick-twentyseventeen-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'drick_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

This works on the home page (the menu loads toggled open) but not on any subpages? I checked the functions.php and there's no conditional statements to suggest it should only affect the home page.  Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

Comment: Can you post a link to the site in question?

Comment: https://billingsymca.org.  I also noticed that the console is reporting that it failed to load the parent theme's navigation.js. But if I dequeued it, it wouldn't try to load at all would it?

Then if I go into the parent theme navigation.js and manually change the aria-expanded to "true" and add a jQuery "addClass" to the main navigation to be "toggled-on", it works. So making changes to navigation.js in the parent theme is reflected on the site, even though the console says it failed to load?  Obviously I don't want the solution to be editing parent template files :) Thanks!